# Is this a proper way to go about finding a (general) solution to the 1d heat equation?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, partial-differential-equations, heat-equation

So I'm trying to get a grasp on the separation of variables method - which, as I understand, basically says that $u(x,t) = \varphi(x)G(t)$.

This is how I understand the process:

So given the PDE $\frac{\partial{u}}{\partial{t}} = k\frac{\partial^2{u}}{\partial{x^2}}$, this implies that it can be rewritten as $\frac{\partial}{\partial{t}}(\varphi(x)G(t)) = k\frac{\partial^2}{\partial{x^2}}(\varphi(x)G(t))$, which can be factored to $$\varphi(x)\frac{\mathrm{d}G}{\mathrm{d}t} = kG(t)\frac{\mathrm{d}^2\varphi}{\mathrm{d}x^2}$$

Dividing both sides by $\varphi(x)G(t)$ (as well as by $k$, because I've heard that makes it easier), we get each side as a function of a single variable - the left a function of t, and the right a function of x, which is then set equal to a constant $-\lambda$, since they have to equal the same thing:

$$\frac{1}{kG(t)}\frac{\mathrm{d}G}{\mathrm{d}t} = \frac{1}{\varphi(x)}\frac{\mathrm{d}^2\varphi}{\mathrm{d}x^2} = -\lambda$$

So solving the ODE $\frac{1}{G}\frac{\mathrm{d}G}{\mathrm{d}t} = -k\lambda$, we can write it as $\frac{\mathrm{d}G}{G} = -k\lambda\mathrm{d}t$. Integrating both sides gives the equation $\ln(G)=-k\lambda t + c_1$, and solving for G we get $G = c_1e^{-k\lambda t}$.

To solve the other, I used undetermined coefficients and found that solving the characteristic equation gave complex roots $\pm\sqrt{\lambda}\,i$, leading to the homogeneous solution $\varphi = c_2\cos{\sqrt{\lambda}}+c_3\sin{\sqrt{\lambda}}$.

Then $$u(x,t) = \varphi(x)G(t) = (c_1e^{-k\lambda t}
)(c_2\cos{\sqrt{\lambda}}+c_3\sin{\sqrt{\lambda}})$$
$$ = Ae^{-k\lambda t}\cos{\sqrt{\lambda}}+Be^{-k\lambda t}\sin{\sqrt{\lambda}}$$

Where $A = c_1c_2$ and $B = c_1c_3$.

Is this solution correct?

Comment: You have omitted the $x$ variable from your solutions. Also, you need endpoint conditions if $x$ is on a finite interval, and other types of conditions if the interval is infinite.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your solution is correct, but the method that you use doesn't gives the GENERAL solution. It only gives PARTICULAR solutions on the predetermined form $\varphi(x)G(t)$ and on the form of any linear combination of those particular solutions :
$$u(x,t)=\sum_{\substack{ any\: \lambda }} A_{(\lambda)}  e^{-k\lambda t}\cos(\sqrt{\lambda} \,x) +\sum_{\substack{ any\: \lambda  }}  B_{(\lambda)}  e^{-k\lambda t}\sin(\sqrt{\lambda} \,x) $$
where $A$ and $B$ are any functions of $\lambda$.

These kind of solutions are finite or infinite series.

The above discret form can be extended to :
$$u(x,t)=\int A(\lambda)  e^{-k\lambda t}\cos(\sqrt{\lambda} \,x)\:d\lambda +\int B(\lambda)  e^{-k\lambda t}\sin(\sqrt{\lambda} \,x) \:d\lambda$$
with defined integrals on limited or infinite range.

Also, they are solutions in case of negative $\lambda$, similar to above but with hyperbolic functions instead of circular functions. And even more generally complex solutions with complex $\lambda$.

Comment: do we need an x in the trig part?

Comment: @Maesumi . Of course. Typo corrected. Thank you very much for the comment.